# setting an HTML option value to the empty string

Tags: html

I have the following HTML code used to create  on a page:

```
<select>
    <option value="" selected>test</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
</select>
```

But when looking at the HTML in Google Chrome's DOM inspector it looks like this:

```
<select>
    <option value selected>test</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
</select>
```

See the difference?  For the first `<option>...</option>`, `value=""` is turned into just `value`.  The value, when set to the empty string is simply discarded.  Is there any way to set the value of an option tag to the empty string?  I need this because I'm pulling elements out of a database to create a `<select>` menu.  Each `<option>` will have it's `value` set to value of a database element and some of those elements have the empty string as their value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just Google Chrome's DOM inspector's notation (removes '=""' from attributes). If you inspect it with FireBug or simply view the source then you will see it is OK.

Your sample code produces this in Google Chrome:

[image: Chrome's inspector removing the quotes and equal sign]

And this is the result in FireFox:

[image: FireBug showing that correctly]

So don't worry about that.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems like a dumb design.

Comment: This does not answer if there is actually an issue or difference when authoring the HTML without the empty string in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

bob
as Hanky said you can use
`selected = "selected" or ""`
so the code will be :

```
<select>
<option value="" selected="selected">test</option>
<option value="test2">test2</option>
```

or

```
<select>
<option value="" selected="">test</option>
<option value="test2">test2</option>
```

Checking this article may help :
[W3 option language reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="" selected="selected">test</option>
```

This means value is empty string. Even if dom inspector in chrome shows you like that